# Could μετά (meta) be translated as "during" in Acts 20:6?

Tags: greek

The word μετά ([G3326 - meta - Strong's Greek Lexicon](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g3326/kjv/tr/0-1/)) is translated as "with" 345 times,
as "after" 88 times, as "among" 5 times, … .

It appears in Acts 20:6:

> … we sailed away from Philippi after the Days of Unleavened Bread …

Throughout the scriptures, other meanings occur 4 times as often as "after",
so could this word reasonably be translated as something other than "after", such as "*during the days of Unleavened Bread*"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two cases must be considered when translating μετά according to BDAG:

**A: with genitive:**

1. marker of placement, with among, in company with something, eg, Mark 1:13, 14:44, etc
2. marker of association in general sense denoting the company within which something take place, eg, Matt 20:20, Mark 1:29, etc
3. marker of attendant circumstances of something that takes place, with, eg, Luke 14:9, etc

**B: with accusative:** (as in **Acts 20:6**)

In our literature (NT, etc) only with the meaning ***after, behind***.

1. Marker of position that is behind something, *behind*, eg, Heb 9:3
2. Marker of time after another point of time, *after*, eg, Matt 25:19, Heb 4:7, Matt 17:1, Mark 9:2, Matt 27:63, Mark 8:31, 10:34, Luke 2:46, Matt 26:2, Mark 14:1, Acts 15:36, 24:24, Luke 15:13, Acts 1:5, 28:11, Gal 1:18, 3:17, etc, etc (many more)

Thus, the translation "after" is extremely common, and the translation "during" is unknown.

Comment: @RayButterworth - my apologies - quite correct of you point out my error.  I have now corrected it.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Daniel B Wallace in *Beyond the Basics* (p377) lists five meanings of *meta* :

**With Genitive**

- Association/accompaniment . . . *with, in company with*
- Spatial . . . *with, among*
- Manner . . . *with*

**With Accusative** (as, here, in Acts 20:6, see below)

- Temporal . . . *after, behind*
- Spatial (rare) . . . *after, behind*

So 'after', by Daniel B Wallace's reckoning, would be correct.

---

Note : *emeras* (days) could be either genitive singular or accusative plural but the context and the article, *tas*, make it clear that it is definitely accusative plural. See *Bagster's Analytical Greek Lexicon* p87.